# Populate Azure Data Factory with SQL Query that has complex views

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory, by using the block "Copy Activity",
you can get data from queries that include a table.
Sometimes a table can be seen as a Dataset but what about views ?

can I include in my Copy Activity Queries like

```
SELECT * FROM l2.View_table
```

or

```
select * from l2.view_table vt
INNER JOIN l2.tableA ta on ta.id = vt.id
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a view or a query as your source.

Set "use query" to query in source options, and paste in your query.
[image: copy source]